# Usual Terminology to name a list of list

Tags: list, language-agnostic, naming-conventions, terminology, naming

I frequently have to deal with `list of list of my item-type` in my scripts.

Most of the time, I'm reducing the `list of my item-type` into `items` with a plural to indicate a collection. Following this convention, I would consequently name my `list of list of my item-type` : `list_items`

However I might as well have to deal with some `list of list_items`.

So I was wondering if there were any terminology, name, to use so as to indicate the concept `list of list of` (or even `sequence of sequence of` or `generator of generator of`)

I first thought of `2D-Array`, but it's not appropriate since all lists may not have the same length.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Value;


Value             value
list<Value>       values;

typedef list<Value> ValueList;
ValueList           valueList;

list<ValueList> valueLists;
```

I would not go any further. Usually you should not name you data types based on its content. The name should try to express the semantics.

Sure you have a list of values, but that does it mean? Is it a List of Features? then you should call it so. That does the List of Featurelists represent? is it your Groundtruth data of your classifier? Hope you got the point.

Comment: as I explained in the question I said adding an s to the type encompasses the use of a container. this is ok and straightforward. I was asking for a data structure name with a feeling of Quipu: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quipu . It seems the terminoly doesn't exists yet.